# How can I permanently save the columns selection in the Search Messages window in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird

It is possible to add / remove visible columns in the lower half of the Search Messages window of Mozilla Thunderbird (V52.9.1 (32-Bit)). However, after closing and reopening this window, only the default columns are displayed, and the selection is set back to default. Is there a way to make any specific selection permanent?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?  I can't figure out exactly what layout or area you're looking at that contains column selections in the search window.  Also, V52.9 is pretty old, it's up to V60.6.  Is there a reason you aren't updating it?

Comment: ... V52.9 is the last that supports XP :-(

Comment: I'm not familiar with that screen, and the non-English labels make it tough to figure out what I'm looking at.  Good luck with this, though.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot is for Edit > Find > Search Messages aka ctrl+shift+F

And the answer is no.  This feature is requested in bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297251